# Exception when getting data from form Django

Tags: python, django

When I try to perform the following calculation:

```
self.total * ((100 + self.tax) / 100)
```

I get:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

I get the value with:

```
offer = offer_form.save(commit=False)
offer.tax = offer_form.cleaned_data['tax'].value,
```

I thought .value is supposed to give me the value of the form, which in this case is a ChoiceField. I used to create the object like the following and it used to work:

```
offer = Offer(
    ...
    tax=offer_form.cleaned_data['tax_model'].value,
    ...
)
```

## models.py

Tax field in offer:

```
tax = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, validators=[MinValueValidator(0),MaxValueValidator(100)])
```

Tax object I select from ChoiceField:

```
value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, validators=[MinValueValidator(0),MaxValueValidator(100)])
```

When I print offer_form.cleaned_data['tax'].value this is what I get:

```
65.00
```

My question is: Why did it use to work when I used method Instance() and not when I attribute the value to the variable.
And also, how can I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra comma, here:

```
offer.tax = offer_form.cleaned_data['tax'].value,
```

which makes it a tuple..

Comment: I can not believe I spent 2 hours with this stupid syntax error.

Comment: happens to the best of us ;-)